# How can I show only some checkbox in multiple select box of JQGrid base on conditions

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid use `multiselect: true` flag, it shows like the below. Now I want to ask how can I show checkbox in some rows, else hide all. For example, show checkbox in rows have ID includes `44`, `40`, `32`, `26` (all of them passed my conditions), so the rest will be hidden (not passed my conditions).
When I click in the check all in the header, jqgrid needs to selecting row had ID `44`, `40`, `32`, `26` and exclude others.

My conditions have been got from rows object.

Someone, please help me, I have researched for two days but not got any result about that.

[image]

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used?

Comment: @TonyTomov I used version 4.7.1

Answer (score 0):

You use a very old version and I'm not sure if this is supported. Anyway you can try. In order not to select certain rows with check all box you will need to add a class '**ui-state-disabled**' to that row. Usually you can do this two ways:

1. use **rowattr** event to do this (this is done only when row is inserted)
2. if you know the id of the row in the grid

For rowattr event your code can look like this:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    ...
    rowattr : function( rowData ) {
        if( rowData.myfield === "A") {
            return { "class": "ui-state-disabled" };
        } else {
            return {};
        }
    },
    ...
});
```

It is a good to read the docs for this event.

For the second case you will just use jQuery like

```
$("#my_row_id", "#grid_id").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
```

Comment: Thank you for your helping. I have stopped this project and can not try your answer. Wish all best to you.